# C# : How to keep track of each file added in a directory and log fileinfo into a file?

Tags: c#, logging, file-io, filesystemwatcher

I have a folder(lets call it folder1) where new files are added continously. I maintain a log file (containing file full path and size) for each file present in folder1. This log file I would be using to copy files from folder1 to folder2.

This is a continous process for which I would be writing a windows service, but thats for later.

To start with I am thinking in terms of having a timer/filesystem watcher which will monitor the folder and look up for changes and on the event loop through the file list in folder1 and add the fileinfo(i.e. file path and size) to my log file(which would be a normal .txt file).

My question is it an efficient way of doing this ? Is there any fast or efficient way?

Any feedback or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class. It's intended to do just what you're looking for.

In particular you're going to want to handle the [`Created`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created.aspx) event. There's a very complete sample on MSDN which shows you how to set that up.

Comment: That's what my plan is. But my question is are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: I think you'd have to ask yourself why you *wouldn't* want to use this. It's directly hooked into the file system so you won't miss any events. With a timer or other homebrew solutions you probably will. `FileSystemWatcher` was written for precisely this reason - no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: True. It is not about reinventing the wheel, I know FileSystemWatcher does the job but after going through the documentation and questions asked about FileSystemWatcher in stackoverflow I am skeptical over using it. Well if there is nothing out there, I might have to live with it. Thank's though for looking into.